# lpmake error "Partition should only have linear extents:"

Tags: rooting, ab-partition

I'm trying to extract the content of super.img, modify some elements then repack it again. I followed all the steps correctly to extract the contents of `super.img` file.

When running `stat '%n %s *.img` for all images, I get the following sizes:

```
super.img 9663676416
```

For the partitions within `super.img`, I get the following:

```
mi_ext_a.img 4096
mi_ext_b.img 0
odm_a.img 755478528
odm_b.img 0
product_a.img 2827481088
product_b.img 0
system_a.img 644575232
system_b.img 0
system_dlkm_a.img 98304
system_dlkm_b.img 0
system_ext_a.img 503472128
system_ext_b.img 0
vendor_a.img 1484333056
vendor_b.img 0
vendor_dlkm_a.img 37294080
vendor_dlkm_b.img 0
```

I noticed that the sum of the partitions is `6252732416` which is less than the `super.img` size (don't know if this is the problem)

Now, without even modifying any partition content, I wanted to use `lpmake` to re-create the `super.img` again, hence, I created this batch

```
lpmake \
 --metadata-size 4096 \
 --super-name super \
 --metadata-slots 2 \
 --device super:9663676416 \
 --group main:6252736512 \
 --partition system_a:readonly:644575232:main --image system_a=./system_a.img  \
 --partition system_b:readonly:0:main --image system_b=./system_b.img \
 --partition system_ext_a:readonly:503472128:main --image system_ext_a=./system_ext_a.img  \
 --partition system_ext_b:readonly:0:main --image system_ext_b=./system_ext_b.img \
 --partition system_dlkm_a:readonly:98304:main --image system_dlkm_a=./system_dlkm_a.img \
 --partition system_dlkm_b:readonly:0:main --image system_dlkm_b=./system_dlkm_b.img \
 --partition product_a:readonly:2827481088:main --image product_a=./product_a.img  \
 --partition product_b:readonly:0:main --image product_b=./product_b.img \
 --partition vendor_a:readonly:1484333056:main --image vendor_a=./vendor_a.img \
 --partition vendor_b:readonly:0:main --image vendor_b=./vendor_b.img \
 --partition vendor_dlkm_a:readonly:37294080:main --image vendor_dlkm_a=./vendor_dlkm_a.img \
 --partition vendor_dlkm_b:readonly:0:main --image vendor_dlkm_b=./vendor_dlkm_b.img \
 --partition mi_ext_a:readonly:4096:main --image mi_ext_a=./mi_ext_a.img \
 --partition mi_ext_b:readonly:0:main --image mi_ext_b=./mi_ext_b.img \
 --partition odm_a:readonly:755478528:main --image odm_a=./odm_a.img \
 --partition odm_b:readonly:0:main --image odm_b=./odm_b.img \
 --sparse \
 --output ./super.new.img
```

Yet, I'm getting the below error:

```
lpmake I 02-07 20:36:57 3610213 3610213 builder.cpp:1012] [liblp]Partition system_a will resize from 0 bytes to 644575232 bytes
lpmake I 02-07 20:36:57 3610213 3610213 builder.cpp:1012] [liblp]Partition system_ext_a will resize from 0 bytes to 503472128 bytes
lpmake I 02-07 20:36:57 3610213 3610213 builder.cpp:1012] [liblp]Partition system_dlkm_a will resize from 0 bytes to 98304 bytes
lpmake I 02-07 20:36:57 3610213 3610213 builder.cpp:1012] [liblp]Partition product_a will resize from 0 bytes to 2827481088 bytes
lpmake I 02-07 20:36:57 3610213 3610213 builder.cpp:1012] [liblp]Partition vendor_a will resize from 0 bytes to 1484333056 bytes
lpmake I 02-07 20:36:57 3610213 3610213 builder.cpp:1012] [liblp]Partition vendor_dlkm_a will resize from 0 bytes to 37294080 bytes
lpmake I 02-07 20:36:57 3610213 3610213 builder.cpp:1012] [liblp]Partition mi_ext_a will resize from 0 bytes to 4096 bytes
lpmake I 02-07 20:36:57 3610213 3610213 builder.cpp:1012] [liblp]Partition odm_a will resize from 0 bytes to 755478528 bytes
Invalid sparse file format at header magic
Invalid sparse file format at header
Invalid sparse file format at header magic
Invalid sparse file format at header
Invalid sparse file format at header magic
Invalid sparse file format at header
Invalid sparse file format at header magic
Invalid sparse file format at header
Invalid sparse file format at header magic
Invalid sparse file format at header
Invalid sparse file format at header magic
Invalid sparse file format at header
Invalid sparse file format at header magic
Invalid sparse file format at header
Invalid sparse file format at header magic
lpmake E 02-07 20:36:59 3610213 3610213 images.cpp:320][liblp]Partition should only have linear extents: odm_b
```

Regardless of changing the order above, it keeps giving the same error for the last partition in the script.

Any idea how to get it properly configured?

Comment: The command is not completed to check if the super.new.img works or not. I'm stuck in the error

Comment: try with metadata 65536

Comment: Tried it. Same error

Comment: what is the origin of lpmake

Comment: try this https://blog.senyuuri.info/posts/2022-04-27-patching-android-super-images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the build log and found the part of building the `super_empty.img` includes the full lpmake command, but with `0` sizes for all images. I changed the size of the images of all `a` slot to fit the new sizes of the created images, and the below code worked as a charm. I noticed also that the order of the partitions makes a difference.

```
lpmake \
 --metadata-size 65536\
 --super-name super --metadata-slots 3 --virtual-ab \
 --device super:9663676416\
 --group xiaomi_dynamic_partitions_a:9659482112 \
 --group xiaomi_dynamic_partitions_b:9659482112 \
 --partition odm_a:readonly:1327194112:xiaomi_dynamic_partitions_a \
 --partition odm_b:readonly:0:xiaomi_dynamic_partitions_b \
 --partition product_a:readonly:1524256768:xiaomi_dynamic_partitions_a \
 --partition product_b:readonly:0:xiaomi_dynamic_partitions_b \
 --partition system_a:readonly:965316608:xiaomi_dynamic_partitions_a \
 --partition system_b:readonly:0:xiaomi_dynamic_partitions_b \
 --partition system_dlkm_a:readonly:348160:xiaomi_dynamic_partitions_a \
 --partition system_dlkm_b:readonly:0:xiaomi_dynamic_partitions_b \
 --partition system_ext_a:readonly:457531392:xiaomi_dynamic_partitions_a \
 --partition system_ext_b:readonly:0:xiaomi_dynamic_partitions_b \
 --partition vendor_a:readonly:1512812544:xiaomi_dynamic_partitions_a \
 --partition vendor_b:readonly:0:xiaomi_dynamic_partitions_b \
 --partition vendor_dlkm_a:readonly:13971456:xiaomi_dynamic_partitions_a \
 --partition vendor_dlkm_b:readonly:0:xiaomi_dynamic_partitions_b \
 --sparse --output ./super_new.img
```

It really doesn't matter the size of `--device super:` in the third line of the code as long as it's bigger than the total of images which I found to be `5801431040`.

Answer (score 2):

It means that odm_b cannot be at the end of the statement. You need to order your statements according to how the images expect to be treated inside the super.img They are referred to as extents.

imjtool should be able to give you information like this, but i was not able to get it running properly.

Debug through https://github.com/rumplestilzken/lpunpack somewhere inside at the end of read_metadata
and find out how it should be ordered according to LpMetadataPartition.num_extents and order accordingly.

Additionally the super:[SIZE] should always be larger than the total sum of its parts, ideally you would set this as the maximum size of the devices super partition.

I had a problem like this crop up and by moving the issuesome statement to the top of the list (as it had 0 for num_extents) i was able to create the needed super.img. I don't have the device the super.img belongs to and am relying on external testers to test in the future, but i was able to create the super.img.

This should set you on the right path to getting where you need to be.

EDIT: Your metadata size looks a little low, the device i'm working with has 65536

Answer (score 1):

I'm using **lpmake** built from this repo: https://github.com/LonelyFool/lpunpack_and_lpmake

Maybe it's a bug of source code. I print some log trace, and there is a vector overflow:

```
AddPartitionImage vendor_b ./vendor_b.img size:7 index:7 type:0
```

You can just comment the check, and lpmake works well.

```
// if (extent.target_type != LP_TARGET_TYPE_LINEAR) {
//     LERROR << "Partition should only have linear extents: " << GetPartitionName(partition);
//     return false;
// }
```